# How can I control flow of windows in WPF application using Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I've just started implementing my WPF application with Caliburn Micro framework (it's my first time with it).

I've configured `AppBootstrapper` class and everything works (my main window is shown), but now I would like to achieve more complex behavioral of my app. At the beginning I would like to show only a *Splash Screen* (it will load some data from the service). After it I want to show only a *LogIn* window and if user logs into the system my *Main* window should be shown.

Telling in another word I would like to achieve that kind of window flow:

Splash screen -> Login window -> Main window

I've tried to implement something like `ShellController` that would derive from `Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive` or `Conductor<IScreen>`, but I don't know how to do it without View for the Shell (it should be only the controller for the whole application).

My another idea is to override `DisplayRootView` method in AppBootstrapper and there use `IWindowManager` to show windows. Is it good approach?

I would be really appreciated for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes override the DisplayRootView and use the IWindowManager to display the different screens / view models.

Something like this:

```
var windowManager = IoC.Get<IWindowManager>();
windowManger.ShowDialog(IoC.Get<SplashScreenViewModel>());
if(windowManger.ShowDialog(IoC.Get<LoginViewModel>()))
{
   windowManger.ShowWindow(IoC.Get<ShellViewModel>());
}
```

Comment: ok, this is a way I've tried to do it. Thank you for the code.

Answer (score 7):

In Caliburn Micro v1.1 the `DisplayRootViewFor()` method has been changed to static. The recommended approach now is to override the `OnStartup()` method in your Bootstrapper to show the desired splash or login screens.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid application exit after calling `TryClose()` on the LoginViewModel try this:
In your App.xaml, set `ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"` 
and call `Application.Shutdown();` at the end of DisplayRootView.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct in your idea around DisplayRootView. I recommend that you override that method and implement your custom behaviors there. You can use the IWindowManager directly to show the windows. If your logic is significant you may certainly want to abstract that into a simple controller that can orchestrate the startup events.

Comment: Thank you for an answer and confirmation of my idea. Btw. your framework is great, thx for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I am attempting to complete the same Workflow as the original poster, however, when I call TryClose on the LoginViewModel, to close the dialog, this seems to cause the application to exit, closing the Shell as soon as it is opened.

What is the appropriate method to close the LoginDialog, to allow the application to continue as desired?

Comment: Its better of asking a new question on this